# Not able to display "ü" in String response

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I'have a scenario where I'm writing a string to ByteArrayOutputStream. Here I'm writing
Zürich and the value coming to ByteArrayOutputStream is 'Z?rich'.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
String text = "Zürich";
baos.write(jsonResponse.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 0, jsonResponse.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length);
```

[Value of string in debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEYVw.png)
[Value of baos after writing the string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YExGp.png)

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: If you stop the code in the debugger, you will see that `baos` consists of 7 bytes, two bytes for the letter "ü". It does not contain a question mark. The shown code is correct and working. The problem must be at a later stage in your code (when you convert the byte array back to a string and print it somewhere).

Comment: Also note that the Windows command prompt is the worst tool for looking at strings outside the ASCII range. Older versions do not support Unicode, newer versions are rarely setup for Unicode. So avoid it.

Comment: Another potential problem is that your Java source code is not saved as UTF-8 and/or your compiler is not set to treat it as UTF-8.

Comment: @Codo Could you please check the screenshots I added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything involved is working great, except for your debug, which is rendering the data incorrectly, but that's not its fault.

Fundamentally, bytes are what they are, bytes. **It is not text. Period.**

Your debugger nevertheless is *showing you* the byte data in text form, and **therein lies the error**. It isn't text, the debugger is 'wrong' in trying to show it to you as such.

However, it's just a debugger. It's not an end user application. It is doing this simply for convenience purposes, because seeing '65, 34, 125, 23, ... (and hundreds more numbers)' is rather useless.

A sack of bytes, the way `ByteArrayOutputStream` stores it, doesn't 'know' what encoding the text is in. How could it? That point of bytes is that they are, well, bytes - maybe it's an image file, maybe it's a keyfile, maybe it's a savegame from some game or other. The point is, encoding just isn't part of the story here. **It is impossible for the debugger to know it**. So, it guesses. It guesses wrong. That is all.  You can't make it guess right.

SOLUTION: Stop worrying about this. The data is fine. That byte sequence *Is* the letter ü, in UTF-8 encoding. The only problem here is that the debugger doesn't render it correctly. You can't fix that, there is no point filing a bug report, because the debugger doesn't have the information required to do this correctly, and cannot easily obtain this information, nor should it. This is only an actual problem if end-users of your app are meant to read the results of what your app is doing inside that exact debugger, which surely isn't the case (and if it is, stop doing that, that's not how you deploy apps, of course).